# if exist not working if the file doesn't exist

Tags: batch-file

I am using the below syntax in my batch file. It works fine when the file exists but doesn't work when the file doesn't exist.
It says: The syntax of the command is incorrect.

My script:

```
if exist "D:\workingfolder\Data\formmed\*." ren D:\workingfolder\Data\formmed\*. medicalflags.TXT
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: When a wildcard file spec doesn't match any files, the result is an empty string.

Comment: The command is completely valid. You get only an error when there is more than one file to rename to the sam destination/the destination already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following:

`if exist "D:\workingfolder\Data\formmed\*" ren D:\workingfolder\Data\formmed\*.* medicalflags.TXT`

I've tested on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

The command is completely valid.

You get only an error when there is more than one file to rename to the sam destination/the destination already exists.

If you **want** to overwrite the possibly existing destination file use the move command with the /Y option

```
if exist "A:\workingfolder\Data\formmed\*." move /y A:\workingfolder\Data\formmed\*. A:\workingfolder\Data\formmed\medicalflags.TXT
```

Answer (score 0):

`If exist` is working happily. It reports *true* if the requested item exists - and *dirname*\*. exists - it is the directory itself.

This is verified by the fact that the `ren` fails as thefile does not exist - `if exist` would not generate that message - it can only tell whether its argument exists or not.

So - the object is to find whether a file exists.

```
attrib "D:\workingfolder\Data\formmed\*." |find "File not found">nul
if errorlevel 1 (
 echo file exists - do the rename
) else (
 echo file missing
)
```

The `attrib` command will generate the `File not found` message if there is no file or directoryname.